# CSS - issue in Safari

Tags: css, image, html, safari, floating

In a smaller browser window the css moves in Safari It appears to look fine in other browsers except Safari

Take a look at http://tinyurl.com/mvkkcfg? In Chrome the Firefox - Then compare in Safari

I just need the OR image to stay in the same spot no matter what browser or window size is used

here is the code that Im currently using

```
    <div style="z-index:10; position:absolute; margin-top:400px; margin-left:335px">
    <img src="http://173.83.251.7/~iworeitb/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/or.png" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Just tried option 2

I changed the code to as follows still no luck on a good position any other suggestions?

```
    <div id = 'O' style="z-index:10; position:absolute; margin-top:20%; margin-left:18%">
    <img name="" src="http://shopiworeitbe.../2013/08/or.png" alt="" /></div>


    #O{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
```

http://tinyurl.com/mvkkcfg

Still not accurate

Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have better luck using pixels or ems as opposed to percentages.
Percentages are dynamic and depend on the viewport whereas pixels and ems are static values and will deliver desired results.

Comment: You can use position:static if absolute fails